# Tkinter trouble: My GUI has no attribute pack?

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

a Tkinter noob here trying to build Minesweeper with Tkinter.

When running the code, I recieve a perfect board AND an error message saying AttributeError: 'GUI' object has no attribute 'pack'.

What is going on?

```
from tkinter import *

#code

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, master, rows, cols, box_grid):
        self.master = master
        self.rows = rows
        self.cols = cols
        self.box_grid = box_grid
        self.create_buttons()

    def left_click_callback(box):
        #code

    def right_click_callback(box):
        #code

    def create_buttons(self):
        #code

#more code


a = create_boxes(20,20,100)
b = create_grid(20,20,a)

root = Tk()

board = GUI(root, 20, 20, b)
board.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you think `board` has the method `pack`? You didn't give it a method by that name.

Comment: If you want a sample of how you could implement your game, take a look at [MineSweep](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577365-minesweep/) located in the Python Cookbook.

Answer (score 0):

Because your GUI class is an object not a widget with a pack attribute. This class should inherit from `Frame`. If you want to set properties to the Frame use `super().__init__(**args)`. You must use `super` to construct the Frame, if you don't wish to apply anything to it then leaving it empty is fine

```
class GUI(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, rows, cols, box_grid):
        # Example of setting Frame properties
        super().__init__(relief=tk.GROOVE, borderwidth=5, bg='Lime')
```

And widgets inside this class should also use self as the pack location if you want them in that class group.

Example for your `create_buttons` function

```
Button(self, text='My Button', ... )
```